# Sencha Touch 2 : A simple handler for HTML Button displayed insided panel is giving undefined error

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a pretty simple html. This html is displayed inside Sencha Panel using panel.setHtml method.
LayOut of the sample HTML is as below.

***HTML File***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function copyText()
{
alert('It is clicked');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Field1: <input type="text" id="field1" value="Hello World!"><br>
Field2: <input type="text" id="field2">
<br><br>
<button onclick="copyText()">Copy Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Below code sets html inside the panel.The above mentioned html is truncated into one line 
and is set inside the panel as below.

```
var res = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>function copyText(){}</script></head><body>Field1: <input type="text" id="field1" value="Hello World!"><br>Field2: <input type="text" id="field2"><br><br><button onclick="copyText()">Copy Text</button><p>A function is triggered when the button is clicked. The function copies the text from Field1 into Field2.</p></body></html>';
Ext.getCmp('dummyPanel').setHtml(res);
```

**ISSUE  :**

**When the Button is clicked, I am getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: copyText is not defined' Error.**

Any ideas of what wrong I am doing here? Cant we set the complete html with the   inside the sencha panel.

The running code is at **http://www.senchafiddle.com/#5LdC5**

Please help.

Thank you,
Gendaful

Comment: Why are you putting a whole `html` document in a panel? I don't know that ST2 is smart enough to wrap that in an `iframe` (which would be necessary). You should try using an actual [button](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button) with a handler similar to what @Sergio has in his answer.

Comment: I am putting the whole HTML in the panel as I am gettting the whole html from the server as a response and I have to display it as it is.This HTML contains events handling and frontend validations as well. So, this is the reason I have dependent to display the whole HTML inside the panel. Completely agreed with you that I have to parse the server response HTML and create the sencha native components accordingly and write my own validations as the above approach does not seems to be working. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I guess my only suggestion is to maybe wrap that html document in an `<iframe>` before you put it in using `Ext.getCmp('dummyPanel').setHtml(res)`. (You know, if you _don't_ parse the whole thing... and parsing it could be a beast.) Good luck.

Comment: the <Header> will be removed, depending on the how complicated the button function is you could do this:

<button onclick="function (){ alert('Button Clicked') }">Copy Text</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it as below.

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype     : 'panel',
    html      : '<button>Foo</button>',
    listeners : {
        element  : 'element',
        delegate : 'button',
        tap      : function () {
            console.log('button tap!');
        }
    }
});
```

So, the handler will be called for button only and nothing else.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think the "right" answer here is to use a [Sencha Touch button](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button). Beyond likely not causing this error, Sencha has done substantial work to optimize event handling, and using inline events don't take advantage of those optimizations. I'm not certain, but I have a strong feeling that destroying that button doesn't even destroy event handler there, which is an unpleasant leak in the code.

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Copy Text'
});

button.on({
    click:{
         copyText()
    }
);
```

Comment: Buttons listen to the tap event (not click). Also here you are not referring to the copyText function, you are calling it.

Comment: Yeah, it should be "tap", and you should really have the handler inside the definition of the button config.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.I am getting the html from the server as a response. This HTML contains the events handling and frontend validations as well. That is the reason I have to display the HTML as it is rather than creating the sencha components there.There are big number of HTMLs having validations and events handlings. If I can't display the html as it is then it would be a huge modification in the code but that seems to be the only way :( .. Thanks for the pointers..